# NodeJs - RSS and external memory increases significantly, heap memory increases slowly. What can be the causes?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

In my NodeJS application:

1.Is it correct that RSS and external memory increases significantly, but heap memory increases slowly?

2. Is it correct that the external memory increases more than the heapTotal?

I tried using the chrome inspect, but as soon as i launch the snapshots the application crashes.
Also, i don't think analyzing the heap memory i find the problem.

[see the graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hgCE.png)

Any suggestions?